# getting numbers from stdin to an array in C

Tags: arrays, getchar, atoi

I'm trying to get numbers from stdin to an array. the first number in stdin is the number of elements in the array (the number can be any int).
I did this to get the first number:

```
while(c=getchar()!=' '){
n*=10;
n+=atoi(c);
}
```

And then created an array of size n.
Now I need to go through all the rest

```
 while(c=getchar()!=EOF)
```

and add numbers to the array. The numbers are separated by \t and sometimes \n as well.
How would I do that? I've been thinking for an hour and still haven't got a working code.
Any help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you're feeling particularly masochistic (or can't due to homework requirements), you'd normally do it using `scanf`:

```
int n;
int *numbers;

scanf("%d", &n);

numbers = malloc(n * sizeof(*numbers));

for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    scanf("%d", &numbers[i]);
```

For more robust error handling, you frequently want to read a line at a time using `fgets`, then parse that into individual numbers using `sscanf` (or something similar).

As an aside: no you should *not* cast the return from `malloc` to `int *`. It's neither necessary nor desirable in C. Just `#include <stdlib.h>`, and assign the result as shown above. If your compiler is giving you a warning (or error) about a conversion, that means one of two things is happening: either you've forgotten to `#include <stdlib.h>` as required, or else you're actually compiling as C++. If you're writing C++, write real C++, which means you shouldn't be using `malloc` at all.

Comment: WOW, I didn't know I could do that! 

Can you please explain however, why is anything between the numbers ignored? And how the second scanf continues from where the first scanf stopped?

Comment: The "%d" scanf conversion skips across white-space before a number (and tabs and new-lines are both considered white-space). When you open a file, it has a "current position" indicator, which is updated by the functions that read from it (`getc`, `scanf`, `fread`, etc.)

Comment: but in the case of %c a white space is counted correct?
Ahh yes, I know about the current position but didn't know that scanf uses it as well.

Comment: @MinaHany: Yes, %c will read spaces. In fact, the fundamental difference between %c and %s is that %s skips leading white space, then reads up to the next white space, where %c just reads in as many characters as you specify.

Comment: So if on stdin was "StringA StringB StringC" then scanf %s will automatically read 3 strings and neglect spaces but scanf %c will read chars one by one.
Thank you so much mate! Have a nice day :)

Comment: @MinaHany: `%c` will read one by one, but you can also specify a count, so `%26c` would read all of "StringA StringB StringC" at once (at least if I've counted correctly).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the extra info! Cheers mate